# Dead touchpad/trackpad on new dell inpiron 15 7000

Tags: dell, touchpad, inspiron, trackpad

I recently bought a new dell inspiron 15 7000. [(this one)](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15-7547-laptop/pd?oc=fndaq5247ht)

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on this system. 
The trackpad/touchpad does not respond at all, I'm guessing is not identified.

xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:75BD                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I am somewhat new with Ubuntu and any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to try running Ubuntu 14.10 live and seeing if that fixes the problem. Also, I know that Ubuntu 14.10 has a nice feature that is supported on some Dell Inspiron 15 computers: it disconnects the hard drive when it detects it's falling. So yeah, try 14.10 LIVE and see if that helps. If it does, upgrade 14.04 to it using the Software Updater.

Comment: FuzzyToothPaste: thanks for the response. Im not sure what you mean by LIVE. but when I use the bootable Image for ubuntu it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this problem.

I noticed that when ubuntu booted it showed some message saying :

[   27.076007] i2c_hid i2c-SYN1B7D:01: failed to retrieve report from devce

I looked it up, and found this:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185329

Same issue has been mentioned here :
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/14.04#Kernel

This guy had almost same problem and it got solved by blacklisting i2c_hid module.

So if you just bought the same laptop and are facing the same problem, you can try doing this:

- Open terminal and type in : `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. This is a file that has entries for kernel modules, that are not loaded or blacklisted.
- Go to end of file and write this `blacklist i2c_hid`.
- restart your system a couple of times . somehow I had to do it twice.

This solves this problem for now. Trackpad working perfectly.

Comment: Instead of restarting twice, shut down completely (power off) and then turn the machine on again...

Comment: I recently received an update that caused my laptop's touchpad to stop working again. I removed the blacklist entry for i2c_hid. Now its working again.

Answer (score 0):

An update to [kernel 3.18](http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/803937-installupgrade-linux-kernel-to-3183-stable-in-ubuntulinux-mintpeppermint) solved it for me. Though on my system (with the updated kernel) the touchpad tends to [freeze and become responsive again after a few seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587080/dell-inspiron-7547-touchpad-freezes-occasionally-for-a-few-seconds-then-resumes). Anyone else seeing this behavior?

Comment: I have not been having this problem anymore, and currently I am on kernel 3.19. So you maybe right